# Javac package is missing

Tags: java, jdk

I have installed the JDK package using $sudo apt-get install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel. But now when I am running javac, it is giving the error message "Command not found". I am working from Ubuntu Gnome.

Comment: please refer this, it solves the path problem with java http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5204/javac-command-not-found-after-installing-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

Answer (score 1):

You got wrong package installed. The one which you instlled is not for Debian/ubuntu, its for Fedora, Oracle Linux, Red Hat Enterprise Linux, etc. 
Refer this [link](http://openjdk.java.net/install/) on OpenJDK site. 
Do

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Before running above, I would suggest you delete the wrong package using

```
sudo apt-get purge java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

Is javac as compiler part of devel package?!

But thing now is after apt-get install simply make a query with

> whereis javac

The directory is shown and then cd to this location of javac and compile there your sourcecode snippets.

Or type correctly for compiling this :

> /usr/bin/javac listing-name.java

Linux as usual wants and needs exact names and specific locations.

Comment: I got it solved by the way suggested by Amit